# Attempted to dual boot Windows 10 and Fedora, now completely locked out of booting to Windows

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, fedora

As the title says, I attempted to dual boot Fedora and Windows 10 today and I can no longer access my Windows 10 partition. I'll lay out the steps I took as best I can. For reference, the laptop is a Dell XPS 9360.

1. Shrank the Windows partition by 30GB in Disk Management.
2. Created a bootable Fedora USB drive.
3. Went into boot options in the bios and enabled Legacy boot and disabled secure boot.
4. Booted into the Fedora USB.
5. Selected my SSD drive as the drive to install Fedora to. Note, it was listed as the entire drive with the 30GB listed as free space. I'm thinking maybe I should have defined the free space as a separate partition? Anyway...
6. Fedora installs fine, restart laptop.
7. Instantly boot into Fedora. Upon re-entering the bios boot menu there is nothing labelled as Windows.
8. Panic a little bit.
9. Create a Windows bootable USB Drive using the Windows Media Creation Tool on a separate PC.
10. Boot into the Windows USB in UEFI mode and enter the Repair PC options
11. Select the option to clean install Windows and keep files. Error message `The drive where Windows is installed is locked`. Select the option to clean install Windows and wipe all files. Error message `A required drive partition is missing`.
12. Reboot into the Windows USB in Legacy mode and try the same options with the same outcome.
13. Boot into Legacy mode again, and this time go through the Windows installer. All of my partitions are listed, including the ~200GB Windows partition but I cannot access them. Error message `The Selected Disk is of the GPT Partition Style`.
14. Formatted the Windows partition, same error.
15. Deleted the Fedora partition.

At a loss at what to do now. Can include some photos taken on a phone camera if it would provide further insight?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So *now* what happens when you try to boot...? If you could run "list partition" in Diskpart after selecting the relevant disk and let us know the output that would be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Reached the end of my tether, so I just cleared all partitions and reinstalled windows. I'll lay out the steps below for anyone in the future with a similar problem. I was OK with losing all of my data, because it was a new laptop with very little on it, *but this solution probably won't be enticing to anyone with a lot of data.*

1. Created a Ubuntu USB drive and booted into live Ubuntu, i.e. selected "Try Ubuntu first (...)" instead of "Install Ubuntu".
2. Open gParted. `sudo apt-get install gparted` if you don't have it, unsure if it's installed by default, and then `sudo gparted` to open.
3. Delete all partitions and **commit all changes.** The little green arrow along the top toolbar as of writing this.
4. Create a new partition of minimum 20GB for 64 bit Windows 10 and format to NTFS.
5. Create a Windows USB using MS Media Creation Tool from another PC.
6. Boot into it and reinstall Windows.